# Mail sending using Razor form

Tags: c#, razor

I have a form in my razor cshtml file. I need to send a mail on button click. How can we write the code in the same razor file?

For now my code checks the `IsPost` property and shows a javascript `alert` if true, but the alert is not showing. How can we get the values by clicking the submit button?

```
@inherits RazorFunction
@using System;

@{
    if (IsPost)
    {
        <script>
            alert('aaaa');
        </script>
    }      
}

@{
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form_main">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" id="txtName" name="yourname" placeholder="الإسم" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="لبريد الإلكتروني" />
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" id="txtPhone" placeholder="رقم الهاتف" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" id="txtSubject" placeholder="الموضوع" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" id="txtMsg" placeholder="تعليق" textmode="MultiLine" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="form_main_button11" data-dismiss="modal" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Clear" class="form_main_button11" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: Scary! You are combining server-side checks to show client-side JavaScript code. Please use controllers/actions for your receiving code as this can all be done server-side. The view should just for rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I good option to send e-mail using Razor's view engine is [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer):

**Sample.cshtml view:**

```
Hello @ViewBag.Name:<br />
Welcome to MvcMailer and enjoy your time!<br />
```

**Action to send the e-mail:**

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage Sample()
{
    ViewBag.Name = "Test";
    return Populate(x =>{
          x.viewName = "Sample";
          x.To.Add("test@example.com");
        });
}
```

More details on this [step-by-step guide](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide).